# What's the difference between apparent brightness and apparent magnitude? Are they the same?

Tags: apparent-magnitude, magnitude

I know that the equation for the difference in apparent magnitudes can be represented as: 
$\Delta m=-2.5\log\left(\dfrac{I_{1}}{I_{2}}\right)$
and the apparent brightness of a celestial object is shown as:
$\ B=\dfrac{L}{4\pi\ D^2}$

Some people in my class told me that$\ B$ and$\ I$ were the same thing but used in different cases. This explanation didn't help me though. While playing around with the equations, I found this nice relation:
$\ \dfrac{B_{1}}{B_{2}}=\left[\dfrac {\left(\dfrac{L}{4\pi\ D_{2}^2}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{L}{4\pi\ D_{1}^2}\right)} \right]$
$\ \space\ \space\ \space\ ={\dfrac{4\pi\ D_{1}L}{4\pi\ D_{2}^2L}}$
$\ \space\ \space\ \space\ ={\dfrac{D_{1}^2}{D_{2}^2}}$

So if$\ {B_{1}}={I_{1}}$ and$\ B_{2}=I_{2}$holds true, is this following equation also true?

$\ {\dfrac{D_{1}^2}{D_{2}^2}} \space\ = 10^\left(-{\dfrac{\Delta {m}}{2.5}}\right)$
$\ \space\ \space\ \space\ \space\ =\dfrac{1}{10^\left({\dfrac{\Delta {m}}{2.5}}\right)}$

---

However, if$\ B$ and$\ I$ are not the same, what is the difference between the two measurements? And can either one be used to accurately measure how bright a non-luminous celestial body (ie. a planet) appears from Earth?

Also... does $\ m$ have an SI unit? I've never used any units when I solve for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $B$ and $I$ are the same things in this context. The $\Delta m$ you derived goes by the name "distance modulus" when one of the distances is set to $10\operatorname{pc}$. The thing to be careful of is that $I$ is also sometimes used for [spectral radiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiative_transfer) (or surface brightness) when working with radiative transfer. Spectral radiance doesn't obey the inverse square law, though, so there's no risk that we're confusing them here.

Comment: Ok thank you. So since one distance has to be set to 10pc, does this mean that I'm not able to use this to calculate the apparent brightness of a planet within our solar system?

Comment: Not at all. The formula works whether one distance is set to 10 parsecs or not, it just has a special name when one of them is set there (I don't recall which one, because I never use magnitudes, myself).

Comment: Absolute magnitude $=$ the magnitude at 10 parsecs.